# How big will Apophis appear?

Tags: observational-astronomy, amateur-observing, asteroids

How big will Apophis appear in the sky at its closest point of approach in 2029? Will it compare  to the moon? How long will it linger as it passes?

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/99942_Apophis#Physical_characteristics it will peak at magnitude 3.4, so only as bright as an average star. More details: http://newton.dm.unipi.it/neodys/index.php?pc=1.1.3.1&n=99942&oc=500&y0=2029&m0=4&d0=13&h0=18&mi0=0&y1=2029&m1=4&d1=14&h1=0&mi1=0&ti=10&tiu=minutes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Current estimates put Apophis's diameter around [325 m](http://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Space_Science/Herschel_intercepts_asteroid_Apophis) and its 2029-04-13 approach about [38000 km](https://newton.spacedys.com/neodys/index.php?pc=1.1.8&n=99942) from the center of the Earth. I figure an angular size <= 2 arcsec, almost starlike even if you manage to track it in a telescope.
[Ephemerides](http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi?find_body=1&body_group=sb&sstr=99942) show it at apparent magnitude 3.5 or so just before closest approach - visible but not outstanding to the unaided eye at night - and spending about 36 hours within 1 lunar distance of the Earth.

Comment: I'm not sure if the Hubble telescope will be operational then, but it would be a few dozen pixels wide at that size and so nicely imageable in visible light. fyi I've just asked [Has Hubble ever been used to try to image a near Earth asteroid?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/32388/7982)